# Avoid to to send data when page reload and when the form action is with same page

Tags: php

i want to send a data from my page called is index.php, the action is with same page, so i can get `$_POST['submitted']` in index.php, when i submit data is save succesfully to my database, but when i reload the page data still save to my database. my question is how do i avoid send data when i reload it but the action is with the same page (`<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>`)..?

Thanks..

```
//page index.php
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="1" />
    <input type="text" name="email_address"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>

//still in index.php
if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && $_POST['submitted']==1)
{
    //send data
}
```

Comment: Try `header('Location: index.php?msg=something');` after data added successfully into db

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //send data}
```

Because you gave value=1 to hidden field and that's if condition is always getting true.

Answer (score 0):

The most reliable thing to do is to use two slightly) different urls. The reason for the problems when reloading the page is that the browsers recognize that it is exactly the same url called, thus perform exactly the same request (including the post variables). This does not happen with different urls. 
It is enough to add a query parameter to the forms target url, that way the urls differ but you still have the same script called. You can simply ignore that dummy parameter. After having processed the post variables (stored them inside your database) you send a redirection header to the browser that points to the normal url without query parameter. That way the browser reloads the page without sending the post variables. You can use phps `header()` function for the redirection.

Comment: thanks for reply..so it is impossible to do with the same page, should i add querystring my url?

Comment: As said, it _is_ the same 'page', you only use a dummy parameter. And wether you want to do that is your decision. I suggest you give it a try at least.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a name to the submit input should solve the problem, like this:

```
...    
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
if(isset($_POST['submit']) {
...
```

On the other hand, I think it should be:

```
action="<?php $_SERVER[ 'PHP_SELF' ]; ?>"
```

without the "echo".

Hope this helps.